# TextBlock controls overlapping in Grid WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a simple Todo List app with WPF/XAML
I have a ListBox which displays all the tasks. Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="TodoListWPF.Homepage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TodoListWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Homepage" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="10,130,10,10">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-116,0,0" Text="Welcome to TaskList" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="180" />
        <ListBox Margin="0,-48,0,0" x:Name="TaskListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DueDate}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class Homepage : Window
{
    public Homepage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(new Task("Buy RTX 3070", 12, 3, 2021, "Buy a new Asus EK RTX 3070 and install it into the custom loop")); //Test task
        TaskListBox.ItemsSource = tasks;
    }
}
```

I am expecting a simple 1-item list with the name and due date of the task, but here is my output:
[Task Name and DueDate overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9FpO.png)

How can I fix the overlapping elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify `Grid.Row` on your `TextBox` and in that case both `TextBoxes` are placed in the same (first) row of the `Grid`.

Try this to fix it.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
       <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DueDate}"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want to have `Name` and `DueDate` on the same row then you can replace `Grid` by `StackPanel`

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DueDate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```